# Html.TextBox("Title") inside partial view (.ascx) gets value "Title" from the parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

In my forum project I have a partial view (.ascx) that is used for adding a new forum post. Forum posts live inside Topics (Categories) and both these tables have a column named `Title`.

Now the problem is that when I place the partial view on a Topic page, it automatically grabs the Title value from the Topic, thus populating my Title Textbox with the `Topic Title`. **Not ideal!**

**The code inside the `CreatePost.ascx` is simply**

```
<label for="Title">Title</label>
<%= Html.TextBox("Title") %>
```

I've tried changing that to `<%= Html.TextBox("Post.Title") %>` but then the Textbox value doesn't get posted.

Is this normal behaviour, and is there a way I can get rid of it without clearing it with Javascript?

I've even tried setting a value using the 2nd overload `Html.TextBox("Title", "some value")` but that just gets overridden.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 2 you should always use strongly typed helpers which will correctly handle binding:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Category.Title) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

CreatePost.ascx

```
   <label for="Title">Title</label>
   <%= Html.TextBox("Title") %>
```

YourController.cs

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreatePost(string Title) {
    // do something with Title
    return View();
}
```

Need to make sure CreatePost.ascx is being rendered between

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>....
  ..
  <% Html.RenderPartial("CreatePost.ascx");
  ..
  ..
<% } >
```

in your View.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi @john, I already have the ActionResult setup and I can't do much with the Title inside it. I'm successfuly getting the value inside the ActionResult, it's the fact that it's being populated on the page that is the problem. Also, I already have Html.BeginForm() inside my partial view, do I need to wrap one around it anyway?

Comment: No you don't have to do the wrap. 
Try something like <%= Html.TextBox("Title", Model.Post.Title)%>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is with the code you are using to render the partial view.  RenderPartial will be default pass through the model from the parent view, hence the behaviour you are seeing when the Topic title is displayed in the partial.  You can override this though - one of the parameter of [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx) allow you to pass in a new model.

Something like:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreatePost.ascx", new Post());%>
```

to pass in a new model to the partial view (in this case an empty Post).